# AJAX POST to DJANGO and get result back to frontend

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, post, request

i am trying to program a tool that use javascript "JQUERY" $get. to grab data from several API's in async way. The data is pushed to a query and send to DJANGO via AJAX. That works but.. The data should be edit in the backend via Python and should then be sent back to the front end.
Problem: The data is shown in my answer of the inspector tool (FIREFOX) but not in my HTML.

My HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/my_page/" id="test_form">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Type Keywords ...">
 <input type="submit" value="GO!"></input>
</form>                                      

                                   
<tbody>
{% for task in tasks %}                                
 <tr>
  <td>
   {{ task }}
  </td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('submit','#test_form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var daten = [];
    var input = $('#name').val();
    var apis = [
        API1, API2, API3,...... and so on to API 50
    ];

    var api;
    for (api of apis){
        $.get(api, function(data){
            for (bla of data.suggestions){
                daten.push(bla.value)
            };
        });
    };


    const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000, daten);
    });
    
    Promise.all([promise3]).then((values) => {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/my_page/',
            data: {'daten[]': values},
            
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_page(request):

        if request.is_ajax():
            tasks = request.POST.getlist('daten[]')

            print(tasks) #That works fine
                

            return render(request, 'myApp/my_page.html', {
                'tasks':tasks,
            })

        else:
            return render(request, 'myApp/my_page.html')
```

I have been working on a solution for days and am about to despair. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: did you try `{{ for task in data }}` ?

Comment: thx Jonas but this isn't the problem. I think the Problem is in my js or in the HTML form. Usually i only use method="POST" action="/my_page/" in the form. After submit it always reloads the template with the data. But when is use a form ID as well the Django template does not reload after submit. Just the js is working and sends the result of .get to my backend. Is there a function to reload the Django Template after getting Data from js to display the result in frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming that what is printed in `console.log(data)` is the HTML response.

What you need to do is dynamically replace the DOM's content.
**HTML**

```
<div id="my-container-id">
  <form method="POST" action="/my_page/" id="test_form">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Type Keywords ...">
   <input type="submit" value="GO!"></input>
  </form>                                      

                                   
  <tbody>
  {% for task in tasks %}                                
   <tr>
    <td>
     {{ task }}
    </td>
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</div>
```

**js**

```
    Promise.all([promise3]).then((values) => {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/my_page/',
            data: {'daten[]': values},
            
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#my-container-id').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

EDIT: Updated my answer to be more plug in and usable

Comment: Finally your solution was the key for success. Thank you very much you are my hero for today Vincent!